# Show values in lable based on combox which linked to DB

Tags: javascript, php, html

here is my try to pass the valuse into label based on combox. suppose I choose A from combox the labe must change to 1 if i select B, the lable change to the 2.

here is my try:

**kota.php:**

```
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
$sel = mysql_select_db('test',$conn);
$alamat=$_POST['alamat'];
$query=mysql_query('select * from alamat where jalan="'.$alamat.'"');
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo '<label value= "' .$data[2].'"> <b> ' .$data[2].' </b> </label>;
}

?>
```

---

**com_txt.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>Test Calculator</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
   <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
   <body>
      <label> Jalan: </label>
      <select name="alamat" id="alamat" onchange=kota(this.value)";>
         <option value=""> --Items -- </option>
         <?php $j1=mysql_query($con,'select * from alamat order by id ASC');
            while ($jalan=mysqli_fetch_row ($j1)){
            echo '<option value="'.$jalan[1].'</option>';
            }
            ?>
      </select>
      </br>
      <label> </br></br> kota:</label> <label name="kota" id="kota"> <b> label</b><label>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php#migration55.deprecated.mysql

Answer (score 1):

javascript takes place here

you want to change label value to index of selected option

```js
function myfun(select) {

  document.getElementById('some').innerText = select.selectedIndex;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="myfun(this)" id=s>
<option value=" ">0</option>
<option value="3">2</option>
<option value="4">3</option>
</select>
<label id=some></label>
```

Comment: you want to pass index or value ? let me guess , if you select option in select php will change value of label with result fetched from database

Comment: i think you are looking for something like AJAx

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help